# Binary search tree deletion operation

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a book that explains the over all binary search tree in a very bad way i have so far been able to close study my book and get an idea of the binary search tree however i find  the explanation for the Binary search tree's operation `Delete`

I do understand the two first simple operations:

- Deleting a leaf (node with no children): Deleting a leaf is easy, as
  we can simply remove it from the tree.
- Deleting a node with one child: Remove the node and replace it with
  its child.

However the one with two children is really difficult for me to understand, i have already read on wiki and other sites to try and find a solution but i find the explanations to be kinda encrypted.

I was hoping that someone here could give me a more details or explain it in to me another way ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13755350/1288408

Comment: why is there a java tag?

Comment: @ManishMulani Studying Java however i can see that this doesnt refer to java speceficly

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen Yeah it helps however i am really confused about the in-order princip on wiki it says it starts with the left subtree but this guy tell me to take the node from the right subtree=

Comment: Try googling and then you can put some code if you don't understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the node has two children you have to:

1. Find the minimum.
2. Replace the key of the node to be deleted by the minimum element.

look at this picture:
**we want to delete element 4**

[image]

- 4 has 2 children.
- find min right sub-tree.
- 5 found.
- So, 4 is replaced by 5, and 4 is deleted.

Hope that is what you are looking for!!

Answer (score 3):

If you understand the first two rules, then deleting a node with two children is not tough to understand.

A very simple way to think of it is, go to the in-order successor (or predecessor) of the node to be deleted. Then apply the first two rules and the previous rule again.

While programming, having a fully functional successor (predecessor) function makes coding deletion a lot simpler.

For this tree :

[image]

To delete 8 :

- Go to 9 (7)
- Replace 9 with 10
- Replace 8 with 9 (7)

To delete 12 :

- Go to 14 (10)
- (Replace 9 with 10)
- Replace 12 with 14 (10)

Answer (score 2):

Can we say in short:

*To delete a node N with 2 children in a binary tree (like the aforementioned ones), either replace this N with the largest node of the left sub-tree or with the smallest node of the right sub-tree*